# Django select_related on multitable inheritance

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, multi-table-inheritance

I'm tring to use `select_related` on multi-table inheritance lookup.
My code has some drawbacks and wonder if there are better solution

```
class Parent(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)


class Child(models.Model):

    pass
```

With the above class definition, I'd like to serialize parents (heterogeneous)

```
parents = Parent.objects.all().select_related('user', 'child')

for parent in parents:
    parent.child.user           # <-- another db access, nullifies select_related('user')
    # i'm passing parent.child to ChildSerializer() which expects child object, and it access the user, so it's parent.child.user
```

I can do

```
Parent.objects.all().selecte_related('child__user')
```

but it has its own problem when there are multiple child models (it needs join for each child class)

Comment: Why use `parent.child.user` when you can just do `parent.user`?

Comment: well, actually I'm passing parent.child to DRF child-serializer. and it looks at `user` and effectively uses parent.child.user

Comment: You should add that as part of your question, and the relevant DRF code.